# Why in Scala Long cannot in initialized to null whear as Integer can

Tags: scala, null, long-integer

I am creating my Scala bean which is a configuration to be loaded from a YML config. I want a long property to be null if not specified, but I'm facing below issue. Any idea why?

```
startOffset: Integer = null
scala> var endOffset: Long = null
<console>:11: error: an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion
   var endOffset: Long = null
                         ^`
```

PS: Yes I can use `Option[Long]` but wanted clarity and is there anything wrong with this approach.

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong with this approach. `Null` is an unfortunate legacy from Java and should never be used in original Scala code.  You are just begging for run-time errors.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Scala `Long` is literal data type like `long` in Java. Same is true for `Int`.
But `Integer` is a Wrapper class i.e `java.lang.Integer`

If you want nullable Long value, you can use `java.lang.Long`

Comment: I gueesed so, based on the class def. 

This is so confusing btw! Is this intended or just an oversight?

Comment: It's just a collision between two policies: Types in Scala are capitalized, even primatives like Int and Long, and everything from java.lang is available by default.

Answer (score 12):

`Int` and `Long` are Scala types and are derived from `AnyVal`, which is not a reference type (i.e. not `AnyRef`) and hence can't be `null`. `Integer` on the other hand is an alias for `java.lang.Integer`, which is a reference type.

No, it's not an oversight, `Int` and `Long` are consistent, using `null` in Scala is considered a bad thing and, as I understand it, `null` exists merely for Java compatibility (even for `AnyRef`) as well as `Integer`.

Answer (score 4):

In Scala, type `scala.Null` is a subtype of all reference types (all types which inherit from `scala.AnyRef` - which is an alias of `java.lang.Object`). That's why you can use the `null` value (of type `scala.Null`) anywhere a reference type is expected.

It is not, however, a subtype of any value type (types which inherit from `scala.AnyVal`). Because types such as `scala.Int`, `scala.Long`, `scala.Boolean`... (corresponding to Java's primitive types) are value types, they cannot be null.

As for the `Integer` type you mention: I guess this is `java.lang.Integer`, which is a subtype of `java.lang.Object` (a.k.a. `scala.AnyRef`): it's a reference type, so you can use `null`.

It's probably easier to understand with this diagram of the Scala type hierarchy (lifted from [the official documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/unified-types.html)):
[image: Scala types hierarchy]