# Why an Int cannot be initialized as null in Scala?

Tags: scala

I want to initialize a variable of type `Int` as `null` in Scala but I am not able to do so -

```
scala> val a: Int = null
<console>:11: error: an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion
   val a: Int = null
```

But I can initialize a variable of type `String` as `null` in Scala:

```
scala> val a: String = null
a: String = null
```

Anyone know the reason for it?

**Note** - I am using Scala 2.11.8

Comment: Not an answer to the question but it would be more normal (and better) to declarent it as an `Option[Int]`, that way you make it clear that it may be a none, whereas nulls are always nasty suprises

Comment: That is fine @RichardTingle, I am using `Option[Int]` in place of `null`. But, then why Scala is allowing me to do it for `String` type?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210830/why-in-scala-long-cannot-in-initialized-to-null-whear-as-integer-can

Comment: Probably because java allows it (where Optional was only just introduced). Java allows a null string (because a string is an object) but no null int; because int is a primitive. I expect the scala designers didn't want to bring in a nasty feature no one should use just for consistency

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Null is a subtype of all reference types; its only instance is the null reference. Since Null is not a subtype of value types, null is not a member of any such type. For instance, it is not possible to assign null to a variable of type scala.Int.
In other hand String is subtype of AnyRef which allows assigning null as value.
For hierarchy [reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/128)