# check for null values in Option[Long]

Tags: scala

I am a new developper on Scala and I want to write a simple function :

```
def compute_start(start: Option[Long]) : (Int, Int, Int) = {
    if (start != null.asInstanceOf[Long] && start != null && start != "null") { // I tried ALL THOSE OPTIONS !!!
        var result = helper(start.get) // another function
        (temp._1, temp._2, temp._3)
    } else {
        (0, 0, 0)
    }
```

But I always get this error :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 696.0 failed 8 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.7 in stage 696.0 (TID 99422, ldatanode10ch.nms.ld, executor 145): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
```

So, I guess that the condition if (start != null.asInstanceOf[Long] didn't return true.

Please, how can I avoid a null values for a long (or Option[long] ) variable ??
Thank you !

Comment: `null.asInstanceOf[Long]` is always 0 so the condition never holds if `start != 0`
Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39210959/2928853

Answer (score 3):

You can use pattern matching like this:

```scala
def compute_start(start: Option[Long]) : (Int, Int, Int) = {
  start match {
     case Some(value) => 
       val result = helper(value)
       (result._1, result._2, result._3)
     case None => (0,0,0)
  }

}
```

**Edit:**
Thinking a little bit more about your issue, I believe your `start` value is being passed as `Some(null)` which is a side-effect from some strange Java library that is passing this value down to your function.
One way to deal with it is to ensure an Optional value like this:

```scala
// simulated value got from your library (must probably)
val start: Option[Long] = null

// ensure the start value is safe (without null values)
val safeStart = Option(start).filter(_.nonEmpty).flatten

// Now you should get a safe result
val result = compute_start(start)
```

Comment: It still doesn't work... I am still getting NullPointerException

Comment: can you add the stack trace on your answer so we can help you to find out?

Comment: If `start` was `null`, that would give `MatchError`, not `NullPointerException`. `Some(null)` is more likely.

Answer (score 1):

You can pattern match on `start` to safely test whether or not `start` has a value and extract it into a variable(`long`) then use it the same way you would in your if statement.

```
def compute_start(start: Option[Long]) : (Int, Int, Int) = start match {
  case Some(long) => {
    var result = helper(long) // another function
    (temp._1, temp._2, temp._3)
  }
  case None    => (0,0,0)
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work... I am still getting NullPointerException

Comment: What is your input?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `null` (`Option(x)`), then unwrap it (`.flatten`), then proceed as a standard `Option[Long]`.

```
def compute_start(start: Option[Long]) : (Int, Int, Int) =
  Option(start).flatten.fold((0, 0, 0)){ startVal =>
    val result = helper(startVal) // don't use var's
    (temp._1, temp._2, temp._3)
  }
```

Comment: It still doesn't work... I am still getting NullPointerException

Comment: null.fold will generate an exception non ? I don't think we can use fold on null values !

Answer (score 0):

Your error is `NoSuchElementException`, not a `NullPointerException`. In particular, the error message

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
```

means you are calling `get` on a [`None`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/None$.html), probably in this line (but you should see from the stack trace):

```
var result = helper(start.get)
```

Of course, if `start` is `None`, then it isn't equal to `0L` (the result of `0.asInstanceOf[Long]`), `null`, or `"null"` and so none of your checks work.

So to fix that you should pattern-match as other answers said. If in that case you get `NullPointerException` and it still comes from this place, my guess would be that `start` is `Some(null)`. You can handle it e.g. like this

```
def compute_start(start: Option[Long]) : (Int, Int, Int) = {
  start match {
     case Some(value) if value != null => 
       val result = helper(value)
       (result._1, result._2, result._3)
     case _ => (0,0,0)
  }

}
```

Case `_` covers anything not matched by previous `case`s including `Some(null)` and `null`.